# Related Rates of Change Ship

Tags: calculus, related-rates

> A ship is 5 km east and 7 km North of a lighthouse. It is moving North at a rate of 12 $kmh^{−1}$ and East at a rate of 16 $kmh^{−1}$. At what rate is its distance from the lighthouse changing?

Looking at how the net resultant velocity vector is $v = (12^2+16^2)^{0.5} = 20$ $kmh^{-1}$, we know that the ship moves exactly 20 km away from the lighthouse each hour. This is what I thought the answer would be, but for some reason, the answer involved the initial position of the ship given ("5 km east and 7 km North"). The correct answer rounded is given as $19.1$ $kmh^{-1}$, which I worked out to be $20 - \frac{(5^2+7^2)^{0.5}}{10}$. Why is this so? Why is the initial position taken into account for the ship's rate of change of distance (aka velocity) from the lighthouse?

Comment: But it is not moving *directly* away from the lighthouse. So after an hour its distance from the lighthouse will not have increased by as much as 20km.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the line between the lighthouse and the initial position of the ship is not the same as the line on which the ship is traveling.  So although the ship is moving 20km per hour in the direction it's going, this direction is not on the same line as the line between the ship and the lighthouse.

Comment: Imagine for example that at a certain instant the ship is $7$ km due North of the lighthouse, At that instant, the Eastward velocity makes no contribution to the rate of change of distance from the lighthouse, so that rate of change is $12$.

Comment: I guess we have to assume that they want to know the rate at which the distance between the lighthouse and the ship is changing at the moment in time when the ship is 7 km north and 5 km east of the lighthouse. Otherwise, the problem statement is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r$ be the distance from the lighthouse to the ship, so we have
$$r=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$$
Where $(x,\,y)$ is the position of the ship, taking $x$ as East direction and $y$ as North direction. Then, the rate of change of the distance is 
$$\frac{\mathrm d r}{\mathrm d t}=\frac{x\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t}+y\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d t}}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}$$
Thus, at the given instant,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm d r}{\mathrm d t}&=\frac{(5 \text{ km})(16\text{ km/h})+(7 \text{ km})(12\text{ km/h})}{((5 \text{ km})^2+(7 \text{ km})^2)^{1/2}}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{164}{\sqrt{74}}\text{ km/h}\\[4pt]
&\approx \boxed{\color{blue}{19.06\text{ km/h}}}
\end{align*}

Comment: I know this is an old post, but how do I differentiate $(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: $$\frac{dr}{dt} (x^2+y^2)^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)^{1/2} \cdot \frac{dr}{dt} (x^2+y^2)$$ by the chain rule. Now use implicit differentiation.